# BAT with VBS doen't run from WTS

Tags: php, batch-file, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I need to run a .bat file from Windows Task Scheduler WTS.
If I run the .bat with double click it works. But it isn't working when launching from WTS.

On WTS my action is:

```
C:\path\file.bat
```

The `file.bat` opens `file2.php`, which opens `file3.vbs`.

I have this working on other files, also from WTS.

Originaly `file.bat` runs directly vbs file without php but it also doesnt work on WTS.
Running each appart works fine, but none works from WTS.

file.bat

```
c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10\php.exe -f "C:\wamp64\www\backups\web\file2.php"
```

file2.php

```php
$comando = "C:\\WINDOWS\\SysWOW64\\wscript.exe C:\\wamp64\\www\\backups\\web\\file3.vbs";
shell_exec($comando);
```

file3.vbs

```vb
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim exeName
Dim fileName

exeName = """%programfiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"""

fileName1 = """C:\wamp64\www\file4.php"""
Call WshShell.Run(fileName1)
WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys("^+B")    ' "^+9" is Ctrl+Shift+9. Replace it with your preferred shortcut. 
WScript.Sleep 2000
```

I am not getting any kind of error on WTS, it just run for a few seconds and ends.
I need it to run even if I am not logged in.
The reason why I am using secuence `bat-php-vbs-php` is because I need other things to be done. The full scripts have more than just this, but just like this they are not working.

Comment: why invoke a php script just to call a vbs script??

Comment: I tried it as file.bat wasn't working from WTS. Original file.bat was: 
```bat
wscript file2.vbs`
```

Comment: you can just call the vbs script directly from within the bat file or possibly even from the task scheduler itself I would imagine?!

Comment: just ran a very simple test and you can easily call a `vbs` file from the Task Scheduler ( win 7 ) and supply args too. The whole structure of the above code is odd - a bat file to call a php file to call a vbs file to ultimately call a php file...??

Comment: I didnt get to do it. I tried running wscript.exe and give it the file3.vbs as parameter, also running php.exe with file2.php as parameter.

Comment: Sorry I forget to say something. I need it to run even if I am not logged in.

Comment: ultimately is this to run, unattended, on a regular basis on a live website? If yes, investigate `CRON jobs`